# ElasticBeanstalk worker cron running multiple times per minute

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got an EB worker environment (single instance) running Laravel which is used to run both scheduled and dispatched jobs.

The problem I'm facing is that cron is being called multiple times per minute, leading to scheduled jobs doubling up. This can be seen in the worker's access log;

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:01 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:01 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:01 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:01 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:01 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:07 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:07 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:08 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:09 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:09 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:09 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:10 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:11 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:07:11 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:15 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:16 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:08:48 +0000] "POST /scheduled.php HTTP/1.1" 302 215 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Feb/2019:00:09:00 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.4"
```

Leading to similar duplication in my CloudWatch logs;

```
20:40:00  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:00  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:00  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:01  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:01  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:02  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:02  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:03  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:03  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:04  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:04  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:06  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:06  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:06  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:06  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:06  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
20:40:06  INFO: Processing /2019/20190225.csv [] []
```

I'm using [dusterio/laravel-aws-worker](https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker) to interact with an SQS queue to process dispatched jobs.

The worker has the following in `cron.yaml`;

```
version: 1
cron:
    - name: "schedule"
      url: "/worker/schedule"
      schedule: "* * * * *"
```

My worker's console kernel is scheduling an hourly job like this;

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new ImportData())
        ->hourly()
        ->timezone(config('app.timezone')); // Pacific/Auckland
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For those who stumble across this, the problem was that HTTPS redirection was happening on my app, and the same app is being deployed to both the web tier and the worker tier. The 302 response would cause SQS to retry up to your max retries limit, but each call was still executing the job.

One solution is to exclude the SQS agent from this redirection;

```
files:
    /etc/httpd/conf.d/http-redirect.conf:
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !aws-sqsd
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Another way would be to look at preventing this script from being deployed to the worker environment.